# How to change logo "Apigee" in Apigee URL

Tags: apigee

For demo purpose, I like to change "Apigee" logo in "https://enterprise.apigee.com/platform/#/damuorgn/" URL which was created 1 month before.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose thats a free org you created. You cant change the logo in a free org.